# How to handle dynamic entities in rasa?

Tags: bots, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

Basically i want to capture dynamic entities from my phrases.
Ex: Show me all records discovered in store Google Drive
datasource is dynamic any value can be captured.

I want that it can capture any datasource name.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by dynamic entities?

Comment: dynamic entities like:  i want to show [john smith](name) balance
[john smith](name) is the dynamic entity means in world there is a lot of names but rasa extract only those names that are present in my markdown files. Other name not capture as an entity.

Answer (score 0):

With an intent like

```
- I want to show [john](name)'s balance
```

A message like **I want to show paul's balance** would get **paul** recognized as name entity. If "paul" does not occur in any training data, then the obtained confidence score can be low. Nevertheless in your custom action, check the recognized entity if it's in your dynamic list and do the necessary.

If you want the contents of your dynamic list to be recognized and give a high confidence score, then that list will have to be trained whenever it's changed. Python is dynamic but you still need to (re)run the training step.

Hope it helps!